# How do I install freeBSD headers ?

Tags: linux, freebsd, kernel-modules

I have been a arch linux user for the past 2 years and now moving on to freeBSD for kernel development.

I have install freeBSD and want to compile a dynamically loadable kernel module for freeBSD. As far as I know, On linux I just need to install `linux-headers` for the kernel version I am compiling against.

Is there any equivalent package on freeBSD for the same or I have to install full freeBSD source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in `/usr/src` or you can download from [here](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/10.1-RELEASE/) (`src.txz`).

In FreeBSD the base system is outside of package manager. You can't install kernel **package**, system utils (`cp`, `ls`, etc.) **package**, etc.. They are part of base system - you can update with [freebsd-update](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=freebsd-update&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD%206.2-RELEASE) (it's part of base system, of course). Check [documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/updating-upgrading-freebsdupdate.html) too!